# Applying RemoteViews to Android Notification while keeping default icon

Tags: java, android, xml, push-notification

I'm customizing my android notification layout. I want change the notification background color and text color while keeping other items constant.. icons and all.

I'm applying remoteviews here to setContent to customize the view. Following is what i have:

.java

```
RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), resources.getIdentifier("coreLayout", "layout", packageName));
contentView.setInt(resources.getIdentifier("coreLayout", "id", packageName),"setBackgroundColor", Color.parseColor(background_color));

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(Html.fromHtml(extras.getString(TITLE)))
                .setTicker(Html.fromHtml(extras.getString(TITLE)))
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContent(contentView);
```

notification.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coreLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is a test notification"
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to retain the icon and default layout while changing only the text colors and background color or do i have to redesign the layout from scratch when using remote views?